# How to hide a content on WordPress after receiving a certain number of views

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

How can I hide content in a post or page after it has received a certain amount of views I have set using a shortcode in WordPress?

Let's say I make a post. I enclose some content in the shortcode. I set the content to be shown for just 500 views. Then once the post reaches 500 views, the content should disappear from the post or page.

I have tried so many other plugins but couldn't find any solutions to this. [wp-limit-post-views plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-limit-post-views/) also didn't solve my problem. I need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```php
function hide_contents_function($atts, $content) {
    $attributes = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'count' => 500
        ),
        $atts
    );

    // Get the max counts for the current post from the DB.
    // You could use either an options if the counter is global, or the post meta.
    // For this example I am using options, but it's up to you the implementation
    $total_count = get_option('total_count', 0);

    // Alternative way using post meta to get the counter per page/post
    $total_count = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_view_count', true);
    if ( ! $total_count ) {
        $total_count = 0;
    }

    // If the count loaded from the DB is bigger than the count 
    // property value then return nothing.
    if ( $total_count > (int)$attributes['count'] ) {
        return '';
    }

    return do_shortcode($content);
}
add_shortcode('hide_contents', 'hide_contents_function');
```

The above code, will register a short code that accepts an attribute allowing you to control how many views you want to have before you hide the contents.

In this example I used a single value from options table, but you are free to use any method you like to count the total views of a single post.

To use this short code you can do something like that:

`[hide_contents count="345"]I will be hidden after 345 views.[/hide_contents]`

Note that if you have installed any cache system, your content will not be hidden if the page is cached! That's not a problem of the short code, but the problem will occur because of the cache.

Finally, remember to update the counter of the views on each post refresh :)

Comment: Thanks for the codes, when i place the shortcode on a page, i get (There has been a critical error on this website.)

Comment: for which part? Don't you have the debug active?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function do_shortcodes()
in /wp-content/themes/themify-ultra/functions.php on line 59. on this line: return do_shortcodes($content);

Comment: I updated the code. The problem was that I wrote by mistake `do_shortcodes` instead of `do_shortcode` in the `return` statement of the short code function. Just in case this works as you expect, do not forget to upvode and click the check mark below the voting buttons :) Thank you in advance !

Comment: Okay, the error is no longer there, how ever i place the shortcode like this in a post [hide_contents count="3"]I will be hidden after 345 views.[/hide_contents], i gave the post upto 10 views but i was still there while its limited to 3 views. you can login on this test site and see. https://test.topvtu.com/wp-admin/ username: admin. password: test

Comment: @JosephTersoo did you store the post count in your WordPress DB? And, did you loaded the proper value from the DB? Did you just Copy/Paste my code snippet?

Comment: I just copied and paste, change values.

Comment: The snippet does the half work. The other half work is you to implement the desired functionality to save the counter value in the DB and then get the value and utilise it inside the short code. Based on your business logic, you may save the counter value in the options table, or you may use a meta key value pair to save the counter for each individual post.

Comment: Keep in mind the how to save the counter value in the DB is not provided in this snippet because it is 100% related on how you want to implemented. Me I just showed you how you can write the short code and make the short code functional. But to be operational you should write your own business logic.